# Update doesn't run automatically on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: updates, update-manager, 16.10, repository

I have Ubuntu 16.10, upgraded from 16.04. Some time after distro upgrade the automatic update doesn't run anymore.

I've noticed that if I run 'apt update' then, after some minutes, the Update software window appears correctly.

It's like update isn't sheduled/start automatically, what I have to check? How does it work?

Comment: Under _Software & Updates_ is _Automatically check for updates_ set correctly?

Comment: Updates are scheduled everyday and to download and install automatically if they are about security and to see them in other cases

Comment: Please make the 'u' in the title capitalized. 'U' Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**How to check if unattended upgrades is working:**

1) Check the timestamp in /var/lib/apt/periodic/. Most apt-related applications timestamp their successful run there.

Here is an example. You can see that u-u ran Jan 30 at 01:38

```
$ ls -l /var/lib/apt/periodic/ | grep unattended-upgrades

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jan 30 01:38 unattended-upgrades-stamp
```

2) Check the log. Unattended-upgrades logs all actions to /var/log.

Here is an example for the same January 30 activity:

```
$ cat /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log | grep 2017-01-30

2017-01-30 01:38:22,190 INFO Initial blacklisted packages: 
2017-01-30 01:38:22,254 INFO Initial whitelisted packages: 
2017-01-30 01:38:22,254 INFO Starting unattended upgrades script
2017-01-30 01:38:22,255 INFO Allowed origins are: ['o=Ubuntu,a=yakkety-security']
2017-01-30 01:38:26,336 INFO No packages found that can be upgraded unattended and no pending auto-removals
```

**How to check when unattended upgrades will run next:**

In Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04, unattended-upgrades runs with other daily maintenance triggered by /etc/cron.daily. See your root crontab for the time it runs each day.

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later, daily apt maintenance is assigned a random time by systemd.

Here is an example of how to query systemd to see the daily apt timer (cleverly called 'apt-daily.timer'):

```
$ systemctl list-timers apt-daily.timer
NEXT                         LEFT          LAST                         PASSED  
Tue 2017-01-31 10:12:03 CST  4h 49min left Mon 2017-01-30 19:18:19 CST  10h ago
```

Note that the LAST timer for Jan 30 (19:18) does **not** match the actual run time for Jan 30 (01:30). The system was suspended or turned off at 01:30, systemd ran the missed timer when the system became available again. Note also that the NEXT timer is unrelated to the previous day...each day is random.

That randomness means that it's probable that a not-always-on system will miss a couple daily upgrades each week. This won't harm your system, but may understandably confuse the user.

**Wait, no timestamps. How do I turn on Unattended Upgrades?**

Unattended upgrades is installed but OFF by default in Ubuntu 14.04 and earlier.

The simple way to turn it on in 14.04 and earlier in Unity is System Settings --> Software & Updates --> Updates Tab. The settings are easy to understand.

If you are not using Unity, try the following and look for the 'updates' tab.

```
$ software-properties-gtk
```

Unattended upgrades is installed and ON by default in all flavors of 16.04 and later. Use the same method to change many settings.

For power-users who need special configurations, u-u settings are stored in various files in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/, mixed in among other apt settings. The GUI uses these settings.

**Okay, Unattended Upgrades is running, but why do I still get notifications about uninstalled updates?**

The default setting for u-u (located at /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades) is to download and install packages from the -security repository only. -upgrades and -backports and everything else are ignored...and you will be notified that those uninstalled upgrades are available for you manual approval.

You can edit that file (as sudo) to add other sources.

WARNING: Unattended-upgrades is not clever. If you foolishly add sources that will break your system (like -proposed or some PPAs), it will do so. You have been warned.

Comment: _unattended-upgrades-stamp_ is empty. _/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log_ is like yours and logs the same every day, does this means that the 'apt update' command is running every day? What does _apt-daily.service_ do? And what can I do to see if it is working?

Comment: Edited the answer to address most of your questions. You seem to have daily updates turned off - turn them on (see the edited answer). apt-daily.service is a human-readable script: /usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily. Feel free to read it.

Comment: First thank you very much for your response, I have understand something more. I have found some other information also here: [https://www.hiroom2.com/2016/05/18/ubuntu-16-04-auto-apt-update-and-apt-upgrade/] .  I have taken a look at _/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily_, but I need time to see it better. I have also take a look at _/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades_, but I didn't found anything strange. ...I still have to find what is wrong in my system.

Comment: From _/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log_ that upgrades are runned every startup, but my problem is due to **update**. From _systemctl list-timers apt-daily.timer_ I see that the next timer is sheduled at 'mer 2017-02-01 01:14:43 CET' so in the night when the pc is turned off, but you say that it will run as soon as the system will become available again, maybe something here is broken? If I run _/usr/lib/apt/apt.systemd.daily_ I get nothing.

Comment: Daily apt updates are on by default. Some users erroneously turn daily apt updates off using software-properties-gtk. You can use the same tool to turn daily apt updates back on.